# How to condition a query body to know if it has a file field

Tags: node.js

This piece of code below allows me to create a new data for my rest API and it works fine, but as such I am required to provide a file, but this should not be mandatory, so how can I condition my code to know if my request has a file or not and thus save the data in both cases?

```
// add new card
exports.createCard = (req, res, next) => {
    const cardObject = req.body;
    delete cardObject._id;
    const card = new Card({
        ...cardObject,
        imageUrl: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/uploads/images/${req.file.filename}`
    });
    card.save()
        .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Card created!' }))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error: error }));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file is req.file

Try

```
exports.createCard = (req, res, next) => {
  const cardObject = req.body;
  delete cardObject._id;
  if (req.file) {
    cardObject.imageUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/uploads/images/${req.file.filename}`;
  }
  const card = new Card(cardObject);
  card.save()
    .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Card created!' }))
    .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
};
```